# event java google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, events

I just started using google app engine to develop a web application and I'm a little lost on how to deal with events sent from buttons properly.
For some reason, when I try to use a JButton on my application I get this error.

"javax.swing.JButton is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment"

the only way I managed to get an on_click event so far was to use an html button and use a "post" or "get" requests.

So, is their a tutorial somewhere to help me understand better how to use buttons and other components in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a deep misunderstanding of what Google AppEngine does.  You deploy your code to AppEngine, and it runs on Google's servers.  It generally interacts with users in the form of HTTP requests.  A user enters a URL, and the Java code might send back some HTML and javascript.

A JButton is a Java Swing component, which is used when developing Java software to run on an end user's machine.  Your AppEngine app is not going to run on an end user's machine.  You are seeing that error message, because GAE has a whitelist of allowed classes from the JRE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

It's possible you may be thinking of Google Web Toolkit(GWT).  GWT allows you to write the client/server of a web application in Java, and then cross-compile the client into javascript.  This is separate from AppEngine.  Although you can develop a GWT application, and deploy it on AppEngine.